# ShortCut command in Xcode to capitalize words

Tags: xcode

Like to know whether there is any shortcut command to capitalize the words in Xcode.

Would appreciate any quick guidance..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go into xcode preferences -> KeyBindings ->Text Key Bindings -> Uppercase Word -> assign a key

there is no current key binding see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/TextCmdsByType/TextCmdsByType.html) - it's blank

Comment: you can also reach it from Edit->Format->Transformations